# How can I cancell my UK Visa from Africa, i enter the information online

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, visa-refusals, visa-cancellation

What are the procedures to cancel my Visa application from outside of the UK?

Comment: Do you want to cancel an application or an already existing visa?

Answer (score 3):

The options for cancellation are explained here https://www.gov.uk/cancel-visa

- If you have not yet given your fingerprints and photo, you can cancel your application online and your fee will be refunded.
- If you have already given your fingerprints and photo, contact UKVI to cancel your application. Your fee will not be refunded.

If you have already given your biometric information but are unable to travel to the UK because of coronavirus, send an email to the coronavirus immigration help centre CIH@homeoffice.gov.uk They will let you know if your fee will be refunded or not.

Your email must be in English and include:

- your full name
- your nationality
- your date of birth
- any UKVI reference numbers you have been given

Use ‘POST BIOMETRIC REFUND REQUEST’ as the subject line.